# Entity Framework 6.1.3 foreign key set to null on self referencing table

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am using a generic repository in a code first model with Entity Framework 6.1.3 and all has been working well ... until now. I want to update many records simultaneously and have the following code:

```
public T[] UpdateMany<T>(params T[] entities) where T : class
{            
   foreach (T item in entities)
   {
       var entry = _context.Entry(item);
       _context.Set<T>().Attach(item);
       entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }                 

    return entities;
}
```

Once this has ran I save the changes accordingly and so only hit the database with my updates once. So far so good but then I passed it an array of entities of a type that contains a self referencing foreign key. So, `Foo` contains a `ParentId` which references the primary key (`Id`) in the same entity.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Node { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Children{ get; set; }
}
```

The array I pass in will include items that reference each other. I might want to set the `isActive` field to true for a handful of `Foo`'s. Something like:

```
[
   { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "foo 1", isActive: true},
   { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "foo 2", isActive: true},
   { id: 3, parentId: 2, name: "foo 3", isActive: true},
   { id: 4, parentId: 2, name: "foo 4", isActive: true},
]
```

The problem comes when the first item hits the line.

```
var entry = _context.Entry(item);
```

The rest of the items in the array then have their `parentId` set to null (this field needs to be nullable to establish a root) breaking the relationship!

I've tried reversing the order the items are passed in but that didn't work. The only workaround I've got is to save on each loop but the performance obviously deteriorates the bigger the array.

I've not managed to find anyone else experiencing this problem. Maybe there's something fundamental missing from my understanding of Entity Framework.

Can anyone help? It's driving me mad!

Comment: Are you configured foreign key? Something like that: 

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().

      HasOptional(e => e.Parent).

      WithMany().

      HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentId);

  }` ?

Comment: Read that article if no http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code

Comment: where do you get your entities from? e.g. why first set entry and then attach to the context again? if from database, why gather from context again, and are they correct when you materialize them from database?

Comment: @Layonez it's not setup in the way you suggest - it's done via naming convention but the relationship in the database is correct. I do have additional navigation properties my class that work fine. That said, I tried your solution but the migration seems to drop the existing foreign key (ParentId) and creates another one called Foo_Id??

Comment: @DevilSuichiro they are mapped to domain models, updated then sent back to my DAL layer where I convert them back to entities before saving ... but yes, you have shown me the light! Although not ideal, I have exposed the repository through an interface in my business layer. I can materialize the entities there (without casting), update and then save without losing the foreign key. Still not sure why the foreign key value would be removed using the orginal method but thank you.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your comment :-(

Comment: I suspect your entities leave the context prematurely and relationship fixup sets the FK's to removed entities to NULL... or, since the Entry() call works on the DbSet<T>, the navigation property is not loaded anymore and on TrackChanges the referential integrity sets the FK to null.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Maybe you should show the real class in stead of Foo. Esp. code in constructors can do funny things.

Comment: Layonez Wronskey suggestion worked ! Thanks!

Comment: @GertArnold problem was resolved after Devil Suichiro suggested the entities might be leaving the context, which they were, so I was able to workaround. I would upvote if I wasn't such a newbie! Still, my original pattern works fine with entities that didn't reference themselves so it's a problem unique to that kind of relationship. Cheers